# bootstrap modal issue in django

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I have issues with the modal in bootstrap 4 using django.
When I click the button the fade effect shows over the full screen but no modal is showed. 
I am using django 1.9

Any ideas what could be wrong?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-modal/2.2.6/css/bootstrap-modal.min.css" integrity="sha256-Ad60rSeqfXQzkDAmvKgT7Zm5lgfVJ1dMAwNBCD4rtt4=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#smallModal" data-whatever="">Open modal for @mdo</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="smallModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="smallModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Small Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Modal Body</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha256-SiHXR50l06UwJvHhFY4e5vzwq75vEHH+8fFNpkXePr0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/pace.min.js" integrity="sha256-EPrkNjGEmCWyazb3A/Epj+W7Qm2pB9vnfXw+X6LImPM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha256-gL1ibrbVcRIHKlCO5OXOPC/lZz/gpdApgQAzskqqXp8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{% static 'taskoftheday/js/views/main.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'taskoftheday/js/views/charts.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'taskoftheday/js/app.js' %}"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are including JQuery twice, Theter js twice and Un-necessary bootstrap-modal css. As far as you are don't want to change default behavior of bootstrap modal than you don't need extra CSS. Take look in below code. I have copy pasted your code and removed some duplicate dependency and it is working just fine.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#smallModal" data-whatever="">Open modal for @mdo</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="smallModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="smallModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Small Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Modal Body</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha256-SiHXR50l06UwJvHhFY4e5vzwq75vEHH+8fFNpkXePr0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/pace.min.js" integrity="sha256-EPrkNjGEmCWyazb3A/Epj+W7Qm2pB9vnfXw+X6LImPM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha256-gL1ibrbVcRIHKlCO5OXOPC/lZz/gpdApgQAzskqqXp8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```